# How to create a column for loss type A and loss type B

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the a table as follows:

| Name | LOSSAMT | LOSSTYPE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 100. | A. |
| PQR. | 200. | B. |

I want to write a query which can give the following result:

| Name | Losstype A amt | LOSSTYPE B amt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 100 | 0 |
| PQR. | 0 | 200 |

Comment: Hint - use case **expression**

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
  declare @tb1 table ([Name] varchar(200), [LOSSAMT] int , [LOSSTYPE] varchar(20) );

insert into @tb1 ([Name], [LOSSAMT], [LOSSTYPE])
values
('ABC', 100., 'A'),
('PQR.', 200, 'B');

Select Name,
       Case When LOSSTYPE = 'A' Then LOSSAMT
       else 0 end as [LOSSTYPE A amt],
       Case When LOSSTYPE = 'B' Then LOSSAMT
       else 0 end as [LOSSTYPE B amt]
From @tb1
```

If this is not the way you looking for, let me know.